# TimerTriggered Azure Function that runs on 5th Business day of each month

Tags: c#, azure, datetime, azure-functions

I'm trying to create an Azure function that executes on 5th business day of each month. Right now i have the following approach where the function runs on each day and check if the day's date is 5th. This approach is wrong as for example Dec 2021 the 5th day is a sunday and ideally this should be executed on 7th.How to propery do this ?

```
public  void PositionAustraliaSchedule([TimerTrigger("0 00 03 * * 1- 5")] TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
         {
            if (DateTime.Now.Day == 5)
              {
              }
           }
```

Update:

```
 public static DateTime GetFifthBusinessDay(this DateTime currentDate)
        {                    
            DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(5 + "-" + currentDate.Month + "-" + currentDate.Year);
            if (date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday)
            {
                date = date.AddDays(2);
            }
            else if (date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
            {
                date = date.AddDays(1);
            }
            return date;
        }

 public void PositionAustraliaSchedule([TimerTrigger("0 30 17 * * 1- 5")] TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
        {
            if (DateTime.Now.Day == DateTime.Now.GetFifthBusinessDay().Day)
            {}
         }
```

Comment: Your function's `cron` expression then can be changed, so that it runs on 1st to 7th day of every month, not every day of the month.

Comment: Refer this [cheat sheet](https://arminreiter.com/2017/02/azure-functions-time-trigger-cron-cheat-sheet/)

Answer (score 0):

You can write a utility method which can calculate the required business day:

```
public static bool IsRequiredBusinessDay(int requiredBusinessDay)
{
    List<DayOfWeek> weekOffDays = new List<DayOfWeek>() { DayOfWeek.Sunday, DayOfWeek.Saturday };
    DateTime dateToday=DateTime.Today;
    var firstDayOfMonth = new DateTime(dateToday.Year, dateToday.Month, 1);
    var businessDaysOfMonth = 0; 
    for (var dateObject = firstDayOfMonth; dateObject <= dateToday; dateObject = dateObject.AddDays(1))
    {
        if (!weekOffDays.Contains(dateObject.DayOfWeek))
        {
            businessDaysOfMonth++;
        }
    }
    
    return businessDaysOfMonth == requiredBusinessDay;
}
```

Now your Azure function can change to

```
   public  void PositionAustraliaSchedule([TimerTrigger("0 00 03 * * 1- 5")] TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
   {
        if (IsRequiredBusinessDay(5))
        {
            // your business logic here.
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks... i have come up with another solution,please see the updated question and let me know your thoughts.

Comment: you are forming a date as `day-month-year` --> "5-1-2021". Should this will be considered as 1st May or 5th Jan when it is deployed on Azure. Try to create date using ISO format i.e. `yyyy-MM-dd`.

Comment: It should be considered as 5th Jan.